# ipSecurity - how to add range of ip addresses

Tags: asp.net-mvc, security, web-config, whitelist, cidr

We have a requirement to whitelist the range of IP addresses from WAF) below:

```
199.83.128.0/21
198.143.32.0/19
149.126.72.0/21
103.28.248.0/22
 45.64.64.0/22
185.11.124.0/22 
192.230.64.0/18
```

More detail:

https://incapsula.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/200627570-Restricting-direct-access-to-your-website-Incapsula-s-IP-addresses-

And I'm using .net **ipSecurity** section. But haven't found any example of how to add the above ip addresess without having to add ALL ip addresses.

e.g.

```
<ipSecurity allowUnlisted="false">
        <!-- this line blocks everybody, except those listed below -->
        <clear/>

        <add ipAddress="xx.xx.xx.xx" allowed="true"/>
      </ipSecurity>
```

I'm newbie on subnet mask.

Is there an elegant way to implement this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In 199.83.128.0/21, 21 is the CIDR format of the subnet mask. You can use a [conversion table](https://kb.wisc.edu/ns/page.php?id=3493) to convert the CIDR format to an IP address.

Then set your IPSecurity to deny all except the specified IP addresses. I.e.:

```
<security>
  <ipSecurity allowUnlisted="false">
    <add allowed="true" ipAddress="199.83.128.0"   subnetMask="255.255.255.240"/>
    [add additional ip addresses here]
  </ipSecurity>
</security>
```

Comment: How does the 21 in the conversion table translate to 255.255.255.240? In that table the /21 is mapped to 255.255.248.0. Or what am I doing wrong?